# How to force a Bitmap to occupy the ImageView as-defined?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, size

I am not great at explaining this with words but I am trying to map a Bitmap to an ImageView (the Bitmap is a photo the user can take with their camera).

I have the ImageView set to 300 dp by 300 dp and I want to ensure that the Bitmap is mapped maximally to it and the ImageView does not change dimensions. So for example if the bitmap was wide and not very tall, then we'd expect the bitmap to map to 300dp wide and then there'd be extra space on the top/bottom. If the bitmap was tall and not very wide, the height would go to 300dp and then there'd be extra space on the sides. The Bitmap should not stretch or skew at all; its w/h ratio should be preserved.

Comment: what ImageView's  `scaleType` have you tried?

Comment: @pskink None of them seem to be right, why

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>
```

No need any aditional codes.